# Streamlit: Persisting Download Buttons Across Chatbot Conversations

Tags: python, button, streamlit

**Description:** I'm developing a Streamlit-based chatbot that provides computed data to users. During a conversation, the chatbot allows users to run a function under the hood, after it finishes a download button is presented to the user to let them download the csv file. However, when moving to the next conversation or after the user clicks on the button, it disappears on them. I want the previously generated download button to persist throughout the entire conversation/interaction with the chatbot.

**Current Behavior**:

- Within a chatbot conversation, A function runs under the hood.
- The data are saved to a file.
- I generate a unique key for each download button and save this key.
- Not sure how to proceed from here

**Problem**:

- Every time streamlet is rerun or the user clicks on it, the download button disappears.

**Goal**:

- When the user moves to a new chatbot conversation or clicks on the button, I want to display the same download button, and at the same time, retain all previously generated download buttons.

**Reproduceable Example**

### app.py

```
import streamlit as st import utils  # importing our utility function

def main():
    st.title("Square a List of Numbers")
    
    # User input for a range of numbers
    start_num = st.number_input("Start number", value=1, format="%d")
    end_num = st.number_input("End number", value=10, format="%d")
    
    if st.button("Compute Squares and Save to File"):
        numbers = list(range(start_num, end_num+1))
        utils.compute_and_download_squares(numbers)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### utils.py

```
import os import streamlit as st

def compute_and_download_squares(numbers):
    # Compute squared numbers
    squared_numbers = [num ** 2 for num in numbers]
    
    # Save squared numbers to a file
    filename = "squared_numbers.txt"
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for num in squared_numbers:
            f.write(f"{num}\n")
    
    # Display download button or error message
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        with open(filename, "r") as file:
            st.download_button(
                label="Download Squared Numbers",
                data=file,
                file_name="squared_numbers.txt",
                mime="text/plain"
            )
    else:
        st.error("File not found!")
```